# Can Photon Realtime SDK for Javascript work crossplatform with Unity's PUN2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

We have a game made in Unity which runs on PUN2 for multiplayer.
We have a plan to create browser client with threejs as well, if I use the Photon Engine SDK for Javascript, will it also be able to play crossplatform with Unity side or will it be a separate instance because communications between PUN2 and Javascript SDK side doesn't work, or does it?

I've downloaded and checked the readme of the SDK but it says crossplatform with DotNet client or Native Client is possible, but it doesn't say it is possible with Unity client version.